# Dangling pointer with explicit conversion

Tags: c++, raii

In Scott Meyrses Effective C++ he provided an exampple of bad usage of implicit conversions along with RAII classes:

```
class Font { // RAII class
public:
    explicit Font(FontHandle fh) // acquire resource;
        : f(fh) // use pass-by-value, because the
    {} // C API does
    ~Font() { releaseFont(f ); } // release resource
    ... // handle copying (see Item14)
private:
    FontHandle f; // the raw font resource
};
```

And the implicit conversion function:

```
class Font {
public:
    ...
    operator FontHandle() const // implicit conversion function
    { return f; }
    ...
};
```

He also provided an example of such bad usage:

```
Font f1(getFont());
...
FontHandle f2 = f1; // oops! meant to copy a Font
                    // object, but instead implicitly
                    // converted f1 into its underlying
                    // FontHandle, then copied that
```

And here is what he said:

> Now the program has a FontHandle being managed by the Font object f1,
>   but the FontHandle is also available for direct use as f2. That’s
>   almost never good. For example, when f1 is destroyed, the font will be
>   released, **and f2 will dangle**.

Why will f2 dangle? After copying the `FontHandle` resource containing in `f1` into `f2`, `f2` and `f1` will be completely independent objects. So, if we release `f1` how will it afffect `f2`? We apply ***copying***, not ***moving***.

Comment: @DrewDormann That's not a duplicate. In the first question I asked about an __explicit__ conversion, but this is a question about an __implicit__ one

Comment: What are the semantics of `releaseFont(f);`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth He didn't provide the source code, but I'd guess that   it releases the memory the object held.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontHandle is ultimately a pointer itself. f2 is a copy of a pointer outside of the confines of the RAII class. When f1 goes out of scope, it will free the memory pointed at by the fonthandle in f1...but f2 still points to it.

The "FontHandle" moniker is being used for clarity, but lots of time these C APIs, to separate out and hide implementation, will have the API functions take something like a void pointer (void*) that only the guts of the API has the information to dereference and use. Then they may do something like `typedef void *FontHandle` so that you know what the void pointer semantically represents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `FontHandle` is a pointer, then `f2` and the private member `f1.f` will point at the same thing.    If `f1` ceases to exist (e.g. passes out of scope, or is explicitly released) then `f2` will be a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Note the conversion function:

```
operator FontHandle() const // implicit conversion function
{ return f; }
```

Whenever you need to cast a `Font` as a `FontHandle` this simply returns the acquired handle. F2 will be this object itself, not a copy. C++ expects you to make a copy yourself here. Furthermore,

When you do

```
FontHandle f2 = f1; // oops! meant to copy a Font
```

this calls the above operator. It doesn't call the copy constructor. Why?

The statement `t1 = t2;` is equivalent to:

```
t1.operator=(t2);
```

Since you haven't defined the above, implicit conversion, as you define above. Copy constructor will only be called when you do

```
Font f2 = f1;
```

Comment: The reason it's not calling the copy constructor is because it's not copying a `Font`...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have said the same haven't I?

Comment: Sure.  But you're kind of stating the obvious, which doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth from what I understand, op is asking that since f2 is copied into f1, why is f1 getting released an issue for f2. I said that the implicit conversion operator doesn't create copies, and the copy constructor is not called, so no copies are made, hence since they both access the same resource, f1 getting released is a pm issue.